# "Error: spawn cmd ENOENT" in omnisharp while opening a c# code of a unity project

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open any c# script from Unity in VSCode, the output windows display this error:-

**Output window message:**

[image]

I have seen several posts that said to add the windows\System32 directory to the environment path variables. I already had it added, but still, I get this error. Due to this I am not getting Intellisense while coding in c# and while making scripts in Unity, which is very inconvenient.
Here's my environment path variables...:

**Path Environment Variables**

[image]

PS: I have a multiboot OS with windows 7 ultimate being the one in which I have installed Unity and VS Code, and all my stuff, and that is on E drive(so the path E:\Windows\System32).
I will provide any other relevant information [that is in case if required].

Comment: Did u find the solution yet?

Comment: yes; I just added the path in my system variables section too, and then restarted my pc. I also had already chosen VSCode as the external script editor in Unity. Its working fine now.
Also I remember changing the .NET version in one of the files generated by unity in the current project folder to something like 2.7(I don't remember exactly). With this additional step I was able  to get all code completion and intellisense of unity scripting api in within vscode.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it just after commenting and worked also. I posted a solution for helping who faces this same issue =) 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `C:\Windows\System32` to you `PATH` environment variable and restart VS Code.

Worked for me, hope it works for you also ;)